# Why npm allways err when whrite npm info

Tags: node.js

I'm used to use node and npm with linux, I've got to use Windows now.
I installed Node.js, but when I'm writing "npm info", all of the lines he say me are preceded by a red "Err!".

Is it normal ?

Link of screenshot : [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `package.json` file.  You can do `npm init` in the console which will ask you a few questions then write a `package.json` file, the error should then disappear.

More information on `package.json` here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

`npm info` shows information about installed modules, so your usage would be `npm info <package-name>` for example.

Comment: `npm info` shows information about installed modules, so your usage would be `npm info <package-name>` for example.